# Чтение данных с использованием того же кода, но с другой позиции

Tags: java, while

Имеется оператор `while`, через который читаются данные :

```
int typeArr = 0;
int newObj = 0;
int name = 0;
while ((Name = readInt()) != 0x00) // 
{
    int info = in .readUnsignedByte();
    int Type = in .readUnsignedByte();
    if (PropertySizeType == 1) {
        typeArr = in .readUnsignedByte();
        for (int k = 0; k < typeArr; k++) {
            newObj = in .readUnsignedByte();
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что после того как значение `newObj` прочитано, необходимо перейти на позицию этого значения, то есть:

```
in.seek(newObj)
```

А дальше нужно использовать тот же `while` (со всем что там есть) для чтения, поскольку данные, начиная от `newObj`, имеют такую же структуру, что описана выше.

Как это возможно решить для Java 1.7, не сильно всё меняя (к примеру, можно ли обойтись без `Void` и `override`?).

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия?

```
void readData() {
    int typeArr = 0;
    int newObj = 0;
    int name = 0;
    while ((Name = readInt()) != 0x00) // 
    {
        int info = in .readUnsignedByte();
        int Type = in .readUnsignedByte();
        if (PropertySizeType == 1) {
            typeArr = in .readUnsignedByte();
            for (int k = 0; k < typeArr; k++) {
                newObj = in .readUnsignedByte();
                in.seek(newObj);
                readData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Допилите под себя.
Если стек не интересен, можно после seek сделать continue;

```
    int typeArr = 0;
    int newObj = 0;
    int name = 0;
    while ((Name = readInt()) != 0x00) // 
    {
        int info = in .readUnsignedByte();
        int Type = in .readUnsignedByte();
        if (PropertySizeType == 1) {
            typeArr = in .readUnsignedByte();
            for (int k = 0; k < typeArr; k++) {
                newObj = in .readUnsignedByte();
                in.seek(newObj);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А не как по другому решить нельзя ? Я ведь указал что желательно обойтись без void ? Или это нереально ?

Comment: Если стек не интересен, можно после seek сделать continue;

Comment: А можно увидить как это будет выглядеть в коде ? На моем примере

Comment: Я навел на мысль, дальше вы должны разобраться. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: я возможно где-то не дописал, но чтение у меня начинается с while(на определенной позиции), и после чтения newObj, мне нужно сменить позицию чтения для оператора while, а тот код что вы добавили - делает что-то другое(у меня возникает ошибка) я с этим сталкиваюсь впервые - не могли бы подробнее объяснить ?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы тут делаете, но похоже вам всетаки нужна рекурсия.

Comment: Нечего особенного я не делаю, просто определенные данные "полиморфируют" себя с разным значением, то есть есть объект A, в нем данные, и ссылка на объект Б-с той же структурой данных что и А, но с другим значением.